# Unable to connect Storyboard searchbar with searchController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'd like to use a searchBar I place in storyboard with a searchController I'm loading in viewdidload when I use the following it works, but I'd like to place the searchBar in a place other than the tableview header (e.g. by storyboard not programmatically).

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, 

self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);    
self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

I've dragged a searchBar into storyboard, connected it as an outlet in .h and set as delegate of viewcontroller.
When I try to set myCustomSearchBar like below it doesnt work:

```
__myCustomSearchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
```